# Is frontend slang term is it used in teaching in univ

Tags: terminology

I have a question : is the term front-end in this context phpmyadmin is frontend for mysql slang is it taught in academy in this context I don't want to use slang term

Comment: I'd say "front-end" is somewhat informal, but I wouldn't say it is slang.

Comment: Please adjust the punctuation. This is not Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Front-end and back-end are very common terms, with several meanings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend

They are *jargon*, not *slang*. You *should* use them rather than periphrases.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam Webster [frontend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/front-end) is not slang.